# Does Google share developer's personal data with intelligence agencies?

Tags: unity-game-engine, security

I'm a bit into game development on Unity. Made a small bird project. But I used the face of the President of our country as a main character :)

If I publish it on Google Play, will the state security officers be able to find me? Is it possible to get my computer's personal data from apk file? What do you think? (P.S. I live in a **Central Asia** and we have **problems with freedom of speech**)

Comment: See https://policies.google.com/terms/information-requests, https://blog.google/technology/safety-security/googles-approach-to-government-requests/ and https://www.zdnet.com/article/what-google-does-when-a-government-requests-your-data/

Comment: In short yes. Absolutely don’t do it if you fear prosecution.

Comment: I agree. Not really worth it.